# jQuery datepicker selectableDates showing empty

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have array of dates that are allowed to select in datepicker. The dates are limited to a month (for example March 2nd - March 20). But when the calendar is loaded I see February first. How do I force the date picker to start from March? Calendar not showing any February dates btw

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting a defaultDate and minDate to the datepicker.

```
var minDate = new Date('2016-03-01');
jQuery('#trial_time1').datetimepicker({
    format:'d/m/Y H:i',
    minDate: minDate,
    defaultDate: minDate,
});
```

Comment: beforeShowDay = array, I am using like this but with minDate and defaultDate still showing other months first